# jade - rosbag play with remap

Tags: ros, rosbag, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to play a bag file with rosbag and remap the topics (e.g.: /myTopic:=/playback/myTopic).
I tried with **launch file**:

`<launch> <remap from="myTopic" to="/playback/myTopic"/> <arg name="file"/> <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="playback" ns="myNamespace" args="—clock $(arg file)" /> </launch>`

and from **command line** also ( rosbag play mybag.bag /myTopic:=/playback/myTopic )

The play starts without any error with both ways, I can see a new topic: myNamespace/clock (or /clock if I start it from command line), but all of the recorded topics are replayed on their original name (e.g. /myTopic) (and the replay is working, I can see it changes the values), so I guess, the remap is not really working or am I missing something?

According to the documentation I saw, this should be possible, but I am not sure it is still working in the jade release.

Thanks in advance!
Balint

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239526/jade---rosbag-play-with-remap/) by [Balint Tahi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27488/balint-tahi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-07-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have a Jade setup to test with, but I was able to remap playback on Indigo.

You want to use the `remap` tag *inside* the `node` tag. E.g.:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="file"/>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="playback" ns="myNamespace" args="—clock $(arg file)">
     <remap from="/myTopic" to="/playback/myTopic"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

That should result in the recorded topic `/MyTopic` being published as `/playback/myTopic`. To be honest, I'm not certain exactly how the remap interacts with the namespace specification (my initial testing suggests that the namespace into which you put `rosbag play` doesn't affect the scoping of its published topics).

At the command-line, I was able to remap topics in the usual way, using the same syntax that you suggested.

If these techniques aren't working for you on Jade, then please open an issue: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/22196/gerkey/) with karma: 1981 on 2016-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Balint Tahi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27488/balint-tahi/) on 2016-08-05**:
I tried with your launch file as well, but it is still not working. I have the some services (I guess the default ones) under /playback, but no topics at all.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-08-08**:
Did you modify the launch file for the topics in your bag file?

**Comment by [Balint Tahi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27488/balint-tahi/) on 2016-08-08**:
Sure, I did. I tried several ways... I tried to remap everything in the bag (according to the documentation it is possible with from="/" to="/playback"), but it has no effect either, neither remapping /something to /playback/something.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-08-08**:
Please update your question to include the actual commands and console outputs, and if possible share a bag file that can reproduce the problem you're seeing. Otherwise we're just guessing.

**Comment by [Balint Tahi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27488/balint-tahi/) on 2016-08-08**:
You can download everything you asked from here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z750vmdzbj10x3k/rosbag.zip?dl=0

I included a screenshot, the left one is the output of rosbag, the right one is the "rostopic list" before and after rosbag run.

I hope this will help.
Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [Balint Tahi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27488/balint-tahi/) on 2016-08-08**:
I tried with /ivar/testAccel:=/playback/ivar/testAccel from command line. It remapped that topic. Maybe I misunderstood how it works, becuase as I can see, the name of a topic is like a path. /a/b and /a/c ha some kind of relationshop... and I wanted to move /a -> /playback/a. Isn't it possible?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although it's not clear from the statement what remap the OP is asking for specically, from the [given bag file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z750vmdzbj10x3k/rosbag.zip?dl=0) that contains `/ivar/testAccel, /ivar/testPoint, /ivar/testTopic`, I assume that OP wants to remap multiple topics by a single remap operation.

Although I'm not entirely sure (because I have a trouble understinding the English statement and the example table in [Remapping Arguments wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments)), I don't think that is possible. My understanding is that remap in launch file works for the full exact name.

Using the example OP provides (with a little modifition done by me), the following worked on my Ubuntu 14.04 - Indigo computer.

```
<launch>
  <arg name="file" default="$(find foobar)/myRecord.bag" />
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="playback" ns="myNamespace" args="-l --clock $(arg file)">
    <remap from="/ivar" to="/playback/ivar"/>                      <!-- This does NOT remap. -->
    <remap from="/ivar/testPoint" to="/playback/ivar/testPoint"/>  <!-- This DOES remap. -->
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-09-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1